# Probability of a particle penetrating through a shield

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Suppose that the probability that any particle is emitted by a
>   radioactive material will penetrate a certain shield is 0.01. If 10
>   particles are emitted, what is the probability that exactly one
>   particle will penetrate the shield?

The answer is $10(0.01)(0.99)^9$, and I'm confused on why we need to multiply it by $10$ when the 9th power seems to constitute the $9$ failures and then $0.01$ for $1$ success.

Comment: Any one of them can penetrate the shield so there are $10$ ways it can happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have the right idea

first we must choose which particle will penetrate the shield. let's label the particles:

A B C D E F G H I J

suppose we want to calculate the probability that exactly (only) particle A penetrates the shield. that probability is the chance that it penetrates (.01) multiplied by the chance that the other particles (B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J) fail. that would be .01 multiplied by .99 to the 9th power.

this is where we stop, or at least we would if the question asked for the probability that exactly (only) particle A penetrates. however, there's a chance that particle A fails and that particle B could be the only particle penetrating the shield. that chance can be calculated the same way as we calculated the probability of only particle A penetrating. however, there's a chance that  particle A and B fails but particle C could be the only particle penetrating the shield. . .

eventually, we have 10 probabilities for each of the particles. since the events are mutually exclusive, these 10 probabilities are summed up to bring forth the probability that exactly one (and only one arbitrary) particle penetrates.

Answer (score 1):

You multiply by 10 because any of the 10 particles can be the penetrating particle.

In the case in which exactly one particle penetrates, there are (1 choose 10) ways to organize 1 penetrating particle and 9 non-penetrating particles.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of getting exactly $k=1$ success with $n=10$ particles is the probability of getting exactly $k=1$ success in $n=10$  trials and is given by the binomial probability mass function:
$$
b(k;n,p)=\Bbb P(X=k)={n \choose k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}={10 \choose 1}0.01^{1}(1-0.01)^{10-1}=10\times 0.01\times 0.99^9
$$

Answer (score -1):

For each particle in turn getting to be the one that penetrates the shield, while none of the others do:

$\begin{align}
\#1 &: 0.01 \times 0.99^9 \\
\#2 &: 0.99 \times 0.01 \times 0.99^8 \\
\#3 &: 0.99^2 \times 0.01 \times 0.99^7 \\
\#4 &: 0.99^3 \times 0.01 \times 0.99^6 \\
\#5 &: 0.99^4 \times 0.01 \times 0.99^5 \\
\#6 &: 0.99^5 \times 0.01 \times 0.99^4 \\
\#7 &: 0.99^6 \times 0.01 \times 0.99^3 \\
\#8 &: 0.99^7 \times 0.01 \times 0.99^2 \\
\#9 &: 0.99^8 \times 0.01 \times 0.99 \\
\#10 &: 0.99^9 \times 0.01  \\
\end{align}$

...all exclusive (selecting one option excludes all the other options). Obviously in each case the resulting chance is the same. Total probability then is the sum of these, $10\times  0.01 \times 0.99^9$

**If** the question were asking the chance that **exactly two** particles penetrated the shield, the same exercise for every possible pair would be rather dull and instead we should turn to the combinatorics option, using the binomial coeeficient directly: $\binom {10}{2} = \frac {10!}{2!\,8!} = \frac {10\cdot 9 }{2} = 45$ possible pairings, multiplied by the identical chance of each considered pair, $0.01^2\cdot 0.99^8$